# Move data to historical table after delete

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I would like to know what is the best approach for creating a historical table for some table and automatically move deleted rows to this new table with same columns + deleted time.

For example:
When I delete a row from a PRODUCT table it will move to PRODUCT_H table with deleted time column.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please share some code you use for deletion of product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option is set trigger in database something like that :

```
    CREATE TRIGGER movetohistorical
        ON dbo.PRODUCT 
        FOR DELETE
    AS

    INSERT Product_H
    SELECT * FROM dbo.PRODUCT 
    WHERE PRODUCT.id IN(SELECT deleted.id FROM deleted)


GO
```

Comment: Yes, this is the best approach but it fits only if you'd like to perform operation inside SQL Server. If you wanted to log this operation on external server (e.g. application server), this will not meet your requirements.

Comment: The trigger will fire even you delete row using EF

Answer (score 0):

The easisest way to do it is to implement a trigger in the database.

You can create the trigger using [CREATE TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx).

You don't have to worry about the trigger in your application code.

The trigger should be an `AFTER DELETE` trigger, which will execute whenever a row (or several rows) is (are) deleted.

You can read this article which implements nearly what you need (it implements a history table, but doesn't record the current datetime): [SQL Server: Coding the After Delete Trigger in SQL Server](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/41468/sql-server-coding-the-after-delete-trigger-in-sql-server/). In fact, you have to make only a little change. In the sample, the insertion in the histroy table uses `SELECT * FROM ...`. To do what you need, you simply have to add the [GETDATE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) function like this: `SELECT *, GETDATE() FROM ...`. of course the destination table must have this date column at the end (if something goes wrong, simply specify the column names, instead of using the star).

Any other option will imply adding code to your application, and will require extra communication between your app and the SQL Server.